# Laravel + MongoDB: unable to authenticate

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I've a mongodb with a single user defined in admin, as follows

```
{
    "_id" : "admin.realtebo",
    "user" : "realtebo",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
            {
                    "role" : "root",
                    "db" : "admin"
            },
            {
                    "role" : "readWriteAnyDatabase",
                    "db" : "admin"
            }
    ],
}
```

When using this credentials from linux shell tool `mongo`, I can succesfully do whatever I want over each db in my mongo installation

I entered the following (and they are correct) data to my `.env`

```
DB_CONNECTION=mongodb
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=27017
DB_DATABASE=dev_db
DB_USERNAME=realtebo
DB_PASSWORD=<mypasswor>
```

Laravel is not able to connect

```
MongoDB \ Driver \ Exception \ AuthenticationException (11)
Authentication failed.
```

I am sure it is not a Laravel or config problem because the same app can succesfully connect to a remote mongodb.

Sorry for so noob question, but .. how must set the user in the admin db of mongo so that `realtebo` can readWrite into `dev_db`?  Must I explicity add a user into `dev_db` ?

Thanks in advance, I'am sure is something stupid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is jenssegers' mongodb, you need to specify authentication database in config\database.php:

```
'mongodb' => [
    'driver'   => 'mongodb',
    'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port'     => env('DB_PORT', 27017),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
    'options'  => [
        'database' => 'admin' // <=== here
    ]
],
```